# Laravel project using Stripe works, once I push it online over FTP the fetch method suddenly doesn't want to work anymore

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, stripe-payments, fetch-api

Locally my project works perfectly fine. I'm trying to get it online by transfering it over FTP to my domain. So far everything works but the only problem is when I try to fetch the session_id from where it's supposed to be fetched from... It doesn't function. The app is hosted on a subdomain -> https://[domain].be/app.

I'm pretty sure something is wrong with the fetch URL, which makes it fail. But I did the exact thing that I did with Localhost, but with adjusted pathing which should be correct...

The view that puts everything into works (laravel component)

```
@section('content')
<div class="bg-white">
        <svg class="ml-6 mt-3 sm:hidden" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="12.838" height="12.512" viewBox="0 0 12.838 12.512" onClick="history.go(-1)">
        <path id="Icon_awesome-arrow-left" data-name="Icon awesome-arrow-left" d="M7.376,14.322l-.636.636a.685.685,0,0,1-.971,0L.2,9.391a.685.685,0,0,1,0-.971l5.57-5.57a.685.685,0,0,1,.971,0l.636.636a.688.688,0,0,1-.011.983L3.912,7.757h8.235a.686.686,0,0,1,.688.688v.917a.686.686,0,0,1-.688.688H3.912l3.453,3.289A.683.683,0,0,1,7.376,14.322Z" transform="translate(0.004 -2.647)" fill="#707070"/>
        </svg>
            <div class="w-12/12 bg-navBlack sm:w-11/12 m-auto">
                <img class="m-auto w-11/12 h-64 bg-navBlack object-contain mt-3 mb-14 bg-white sm:w-11/12 sm:m-auto sm:mb-20 sm:mt-3 sm:max-w-2xl" src="{{$subscription->logo}}" alt="image">
            </div>
            <div class="bg-fWhite rounded-tr-[60px] relative h-11/12 sm:w-11/12 m-auto">
            <div class=" w-9/12 m-auto max-w-xl">
                @livewire('favorite-live', ['type' => 'Subscription', 'typeId' => $subscription->id, 'fill' => $subscription->fill])
                <h1 class="text-2xl text-fBlack pt-10 mb-10 w-10/12">{{ $subscription->title }}</h1>
                <p class=" text-sm mb-16">{{ $subscription->description }}</p>
                <form method="post" action="app/checkout/subscription/{{ $subscription->id }}">
                    @csrf
                    <button id="checkout-button" data-id="{{ $subscription->id }}" data-type="subscription" class="text-base w-11/12 text-white uppercase bg-fGreen border-none text-xs tracking-wide py-2 px-3 rounded-3xl mb-8 max-w-sm block m-auto text-center">gebruiken</button>
                </form>
                <div class="pb-32">
                {!! $shareComponent !!}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection

@section('footer-scripts')
<script src="{{ asset('/js/components/stripe.js') }}"></script>
@endsection
```

The JS code that activates when clicking the button.

```
const stripe = Stripe('pk_test_51K1WOQDm7AvXHILKuryQBYtRpecxjXB7GtWrX5fjGRQ2Gq3tlZLfIPrczJ1jazwfARsroGWmBsHceD2L3NS4tAgJ00U2p9jM5V');
let checkoutButton = document.getElementById('checkout-button');
console.log(checkoutButton.dataset);

checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', function() {    
    fetch(`/app/checkout/${checkoutButton.dataset.type}/${checkoutButton.dataset.id}`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'url': `/app/checkout/${checkoutButton.dataset.type}/${checkoutButton.dataset.id}`,
            "X-CSRF-Token": document.querySelector('input[name=_token]').value
        },
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(session) {
        return stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id });
    })
    .then(function(result) {
        // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
        // error, you should display the localized error message to your
        // customer using `error.message`.
        if (result.error) {
            alert(result.error.message);
        }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    });
});
```

The route where the id is created

```
Route::post('/checkout/subscription/{subscription}', [StripeController::class, 'checkoutSubscription']);
```

Comment: You need to start by debugging your code. Is the route server-side called? Add logs to your PHP code to track this. Is the route being called the right one? Look at the Network tab in Chrome developer tools to zero in on the exact URL and what is wrong there. There's too little information to help here unfortunately. Also move to a server-side redirect for Checkout which is drastically easier to implement if you're new at this, that's what their quickstart recommends: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/quickstart

Comment: @koopajah Thank you for your answer. Turned out there was no problem at all... The problem was that my browser cached the wrong version of the JS file which made any 'live' changes pretty much useless. I only found out after a solid 4 hours when I decided to use an incognito tab... Anyways this puts me onto a new problem. When I check my stripe I get the following error: `503 ERR` with body `Invalid encoding: ISO-8859-1'`. Every existing topic says it's about .htaccess File which already does redirect HTTP -> HTTPS... So I really don't know what the problem is here.

Comment: I have no idea for that one, this doesn't Stripe related at all in that case unfortunately.